# Prove that $f(x+y) \ge f(x+ty)$, if $f(x+y)$ is concave function and $t>1$.

Tags: convex-optimization

Let $f(x)$ be a concave function of many variables that we want to maximize $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ a point in its domain. Prove that if for some vector $y=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$ we have that $f(x)\ge f(x+y)$ then for every number $t>1$, it holds that $f(x+y)\ge f(x+ty)$.

I know that $$f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)\ge \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y)\qquad  \lambda\in[0,1]$$

I am having a really hard time, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $t>1$.

Then in the inequality coming from the definition of $f$ being concave, replace $y$ with $x+ty$ and set $\lambda=\frac{t-1}{t}$

Comment: I did what you said and it brings me to this:
f (x + y) ≥ f (x) + f (y)

Comment: That is not even possible to get.  Check your work again.  If you want do it step by step and post your results for each step.

Comment: λx+(1−λ)y                                                                                                                         
= λx+(1−λ)(x+ty) 
= λx+x+ty−λx-λty 
= x + ty - λty 
= x + ty - (t-1)ty/t
= x + ty - (t-1)y 
= x + ty - ty + y 
= x + y

Comment: Right, so this shows $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$ in the inequality becomes $f(x+y)$.  What does the expression on the other side of the inequality become?  Any conclusions you can make from the whole thing?

Comment: the other end is  λf(x) + (1-λ)f(x+ty), I don't know how to solve it if i set λ = (t-1)/t...

Comment: oooohhh now i get it!!!
i just have to prove that f(x+ty) is concave too!
Thanks man I really appreciate it!